# Spring Boot, Azure Active Directory, 404 Not Found Page

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying run azure active directory for my spring boot with web services. The problem is when I login successfully, it can not find a page that should be reachable.

I have added following properties (tetant-id, client-id, client-secret, user-group.allowed-group-names) with

azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template=login/oauth2/code

and my configuration is:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AADSecurityConfiguration extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/health");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth2/**", "/login/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/list", true);
  }
}
```

simple controller request is:

```
  @GetMapping("/list")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin') or hasRole('Users')")
  public String getListPage() {
    return "list";
  }
```

versions of the dependencies are:

```
<spring.security.version>5.6.0</spring.security.version>
<spring.boot.version>2.5.4</spring.boot.version>
<azure.version>3.10.0</azure.version>
```

I have already added redirects URIs like
[image]

as I mentioned when I login properly, /list page is not reachable, it shows 404 error below.
Whitelabel Error Page

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Nov 27 12:29:06 UTC 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

What could be a reason for that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be possible workarounds

In some cases,problem maybe the location of the Application startup class .Place the Application class on the outermost side,so that  it contains all the subpackages.

1. Try to put application class ( which contain main method) at the root of controllers's package.(The purpose is to make the application contain all sub packages )

(or)

2. Error is due to Bootstrap class is not aware of the location of the controller where it needs to be looked.
   Try adding in  class level annotation in your main class: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {(name of your controller package)}

```html
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.sample.controller"})
    @SpringBootApplication
```

(Or)

Try adding thymeleaf dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> **Note:** Also make sure ,if spring boot redirect url has to use the Azure
> AD starter in this scenario, Set the redirect
> URI to /login/oauth2/code/. For example:
> http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/. Be sure to include the
> trailing /

Try to clear the cache and try again.

**References**:

1. [spring-oauth-2-0-client-returns-401-unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67890304/spring-oauth-2-0-client-returns-401-unauthorized-after-entering-correct-credenti)
2. [spring-boot-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370948/spring-boot-api-with-multiple-controllers)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can confirm that main class is in the root of the controller class. Also I use thymeleaf dependency  with spring boot version above.  
 
On the redirects url I have it with https://{prod.url}/login/oauth2/code (it does not include the trailing)

But I just only try these options on local, did not try on prod -prod on the same error-. not sure is it worth a try to be pushed on the prod because of these URLs?